# Wordpress PHP ++ error?

Tags: php, wordpress

One question.

This is my PHP-file: https://codepad.co/snippet/YFF7PRSs

And the respective page in my Wordpress backend looks like this: http://imgur.com/r8Qsjx0 --> as you can see there are only 10 "blocks" (the rows where you choose "Office/Company", "User for new post" and "Category for new post")

My question: How do I change the code to show me more of those blocks? I would need 450 to be exact.

Any hint is much appreciated!

Comment: It seems that the PRESSEPORTAL_MAX_RESOURCE_COUNT is the value you should look at. I believe it is 10 and you need to change it.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thanks for the quick response! just to be clear: how exactly would I change this? I just edited the two lines, that said             "for($resourceNo = 0; $resourceNo < PRESSEPORTAL_MAX_RESOURCE_COUNT; $resourceNo++) {"           to        "for($resourceNo = 0; 450 = PRESSEPORTAL_MAX_RESOURCE_COUNT; $resourceNo++) {
", but that does not seem to work. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: Leo, you need to look at the definition of PRESSEPORTAL_MAX_RESOURCE_COUNT. I believe it is set somewhere to 10 in your wordpress settings. The code at the for cycle seems to be ok, it is just a symptom. The real problem lies at the definition of that setting.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You are welcome, I have written an answer based on our conversation. If it solved the problem, then you might consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was a setting, called `PRESSEPORTAL_MAX_RESOURCE_COUNT`. As far as I know, Leo successfully found it somewhere (possibly at Wordpress settings) and changed it from 10 to the desired 450.